# Error from Aurelia CLI command 'au run --watch' when importing 3rd party library

Tags: aurelia

I've installed the third party library https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-into-view into my Aurelia CLI project using:

`npm install --save scroll-into-view`

I've added the following to the dependencies array in `aurelia.json`:

```
{
    "name": "scroll-into-view",
    "path": "../node_modules/scroll-into-view",
    "main": "scrollIntoView"
}
```

I've added the following to the component I want to make use of the library:

```
import * as scrollIntoView from "scroll-into-view";
```

When I execute `au run --watch` I receive a long list of errors, repeating a version of the following:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\src\choiceswizard\src\node_modules\raf.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:558:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:468:33)
    at Object.exports.readFileSync (C:\src\choiceswizard\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\file-system.js:49:13)
    at fileRead (C:\src\choiceswizard\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\bundled-source.js:83:31)
    at Object.context.fileRead (C:\src\choiceswizard\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:176:18)
    at Object.context.load (C:\src\choiceswizard\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:357:30)
    at Module.load (eval at <anonymous> (C:\src\choiceswizard\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:832:29)
    at Module.fetch (eval at <anonymous> (C:\src\choiceswizard\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:822:66)
    at Module.check (eval at <anonymous> (C:\src\choiceswizard\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:854:30)
    at Module.enable (eval at <anonymous> (C:\src\choiceswizard\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:1173:22)
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\src\\choiceswizard\\src\\node_modules\\raf.js',
  moduleTree: [ 'scroll-into-view/scrollIntoView' ],
  fileName: 'C:/src/choiceswizard/node_modules/scroll-into-view/scrollIntoView.js'
```

This informed me that `scroll-into-view` has a dependency on `raf` https://www.npmjs.com/package/raf while `raf` has its own dependencies and likely so-on.

Notice that the dependencies are being looked for in root of the `C:\src\choiceswizard\src\node_modules\` folder and not in the individual module folders e.g. `C:\src\choiceswizard\src\node_modules\raf`.

Also, upon further experimentation I discovered that `raf` uses `index.js` as its entry-point and as such what appears to be an assumption being made that `raf.js` is the name of the file is incorrect.

It seems to me like Aurelia CLI is not parsing the package.json of each dependency in the hierarchy and loading them accordingly. I could also be horribly misunderstanding the issue.

Does anyone have any insight that might help me use `scroll-into-view` in my project?

Comment: I *want* to like aurelia but the cli is buggy.  just adding the fetch client to a plain vanilla project is giving me issues.  i cant imagine when i start doing complex things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package has a dependency which itself has a dependency.

Add the following to the `dependencies` section of the `vendor-bundle` config in your `aurelia.json` file and you'll be good to go:

```
"performance-now",
"raf",
"scroll-into-view"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I guess I was hoping it would 'just work' with dependencies, but this works perfectly!

Comment: We just created an issue to rectify this situation. https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/530

Comment: You guys are awesome!